# «Брокер-женщина» с дефисом или просто раздельно?

Tags: приложение, раздельно-дефис

«Брокер-женщина» с дефисом или просто раздельно?

Comment: А почему не женщина-брокер? Каков контекст?

Comment: ....впервые допустила к торгам брокеров-женщин...

Answer (score 2):

Все варианты: **брокер-женщина, женщина-брокер, женщина-трейдер** – пишутся через дефис.

В русском языке раздельное написание двух существительных имели только варианты вида **старик (старый) сторож**, но и они в ПАС стали писаться через дефис.

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=65#pp65

Хотя в текстах можно встретить раздельное написание этих слов (по английскому образцу), но оно в русском языке является **ненормированным.**

Дополнение

**Брокер-женщина или женщина-брокер?** А всё от смысла зависит. **На втором месте** при дефисном написании в таких сочетаниях стоит **приложение**, вот это надо учитывать.

**Женщина-брокер:** женщина (определяемое слово) и ее профессия.

**Брокер-женщина:** брокер (определяемое слово) и пол брокера.

Поэтому привычность звучания – это еще не главный фактор, ситуация со временем может меняться.

Comment: Но в данном случае впервые допустили к торгам **женщин** — это главное слово.

Comment: Почему?  Можно прочитать так: впервые допустила к торгам брокеров  женского пола..

Comment: О первом космонавте женского пола писали "первая женщина-космонавт".

Comment: А Вы бы написали "первый космонавт-женщина"? Как-то не очень понятно

Comment: А так: Впервые в полете женщина-космонавт? Никогда не видел "космонавт-женщина" ни в каком контексте.

Comment: Потому что любой контекст с этим словосочетанием сомнителен по смыслу, в том числе Ваш пример вряд ли впишется в реальный текст. Я думаю так: форма должна знать свое место и точно выражать смысл сказанного, а не пытаться закрепиться в одном варианте, пусть даже привычном для слуха. То, что тогда подходило для космонавта,  необязательно подходит теперь для брокера.

Comment: Вроде и правы Вы, но традиция тоже играет роль, по-моему. У Валгиной: художница-природа, а не природа-художница. Вот мой пример: Художница-природа облаками// Раскрасила лазурный небосвод. Здесь природа раскрасила небосвод?

Comment: Разумеется, да, потому что это метафора. Она в данном случае стоит на первом месте и является определяемым словом. Если это традиция, то она в этом и заключается

Comment: По-моему, возможны оба варианта, каждый -  в своём контексте. Имеет значение, какая часть составного понятия далее раскрывается, примыкая к связанному с ней тексту. Для варианта "Б-Ж" подходит такой: _Брокер-женщина имеет особенный деловой почерк_.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы. Остается только определить, какой вариант лучше подходит  для заданного предложения и почему.

Answer (score 2):

"Брокер-женщина" режет слух, да и поиск в сети ничего не дает. А вот "женщина-брокер" звучит нормально:

> [Появление на Лондонской фондовой бирже первой женщины-брокера](http://21biz.ru/poyavlenie-na-londonskoj-fondovoj-birzhe-pervoj-zhenshhiny-brokera/)
>
> Пройдет немного лет, и у нас появятся женщины-врачи, женщины-агрономы, женщины-инженеры, женщины-ученые, женщины ― государственные деятели. [А. С. Серафимович. Мои встречи с Лениным (1943)]

Дополнение. Истины ради. Нашел и брокеров-женщин:

[Лондонская биржа допустила к торгам брокеров-женщин](https://ruspekh.ru/events/item/londonskaya-birzha-dopustila-k-torgam-brokerov-zhenshchin)

[Впервые за свою историю Лондонская фондовая биржа допустила к торгам брокеров-женщин](https://www.inform.kg/ru/istoricheskie_dati/128)

Comment: точно про Лондонскую биржу....я переставила местами женщину и брокера....